# Install Windows from Linux without ANY external media

Tags: linux, windows, installation

I have:

- Windows 7 installation .iso file.
- No DVD, usb, floppy, zipdrive, etc, etc.
- A free primary partition already formatted as NTFS, let's say /dev/sda1
- Linux running at another partition.
- Grub (the one with menu.lst)

I want:

- Install Windows 7 into /dev/sda1.
- (Bonus) recover grub, still without external media [maybe I can just dd the first 512 bytes of /dev/sda and rewrite it once in Windows with "dd for Win"].

> I've already seen some instructions but can't find it anymore after minutes of search. It was not that difficult, it basicly consisted on mounting the .iso and copying the installation files into the NTFS partition and make GRUB mount it. Then installation would follow (hopefully, although I guess the instructions supposed there were two partitions: one for installation files and another for Windows itself)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try.

[PXE booting of windows 7](http://certcollection.org/forum/topic/28167-installing-windows-7-over-the-network-using-pxe-booting-and-tftp/)

Comment: Nice, this can be a last case option. But for now I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need another PC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you have such a limited setup, but you can try this:

- Install VirtualBox in Linux
- [Add a raw disk](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) - whole disk, not just first partition
- Install Windows to the desired partition, and try very hard not to access or mess with the already-mounted linux partitions
- Fix grub from the host
- Reboot into Windows, and try to fix all the drivers, since windows installed itself into a virtual enviroment, and all the "hardware" had changed (no more Virtualbox around it)

There is a high chance of failure here, especially with the virtual->real hardware change for windows, where some drivers (eg. hdd controller etc.) needed for booting, might not be installed

Comment: In my experience going from virtual to real hardware (as long as the virtual hardware wasn't a single core, single socket processor and the real is multi core - HAL issues) on Windows 7 and 8 is quite painless. It requires a few reboots but generally works fine.